# JSP - form submit open html as text

Tags: html, forms, jsp, servlets

I am following [JSP-form-submit](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_form_processing.htm) and here is my form :

```
<form id="nextStageCheque" name="nextStageCheque" method="post" action="/myServlet/stage">
    <input type="hidden" id="SUG-BAKASHA" name = "SUG-BAKASHA" value="160"> 
 <%if(dsDisplayStatus == 1){ %>
    <input type ="submit" value = "<%=EnvUtil.getNlsValue("globals.cheqeDisplay",request)%>" class="sideSpaces"/>
 <%} %>
 <%if(dsDisplayStatus == 2){ %>
    <input type ="submit" value = "<%=EnvUtil.getNlsValue("globals.cheqeDisplayDup",request)%>"  class="sideSpaces"/>
 <%} %>

<%} %>
</form>
```

after parsing the submit button the response `html` is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
 </head>

 <body style='font-size:12.0pt; font-family:Arial'>
    <h1>Text</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

But the page displays the html as **text** instead of the result.
The html is created dynamically in the backend:

```
String html = "<html>" ...
```

And sending it:

```
response.getWriter().write(responseToClient);
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm not, there is only 1 hidden param, in which part I am sending the entire html?

Comment: You probably want to instruct your response object to send the proper Content-Type header to tell the browser that this is supposed to be HTML.

Comment: do you mean `response.setContentType("text/html");` ?

Comment: well yes, it does the job. still not sure what you tried to explain in your first comment....

Comment: Your description _"after parsing the submit button the response html is"_ sounded as if the HTML shown was what you actually send via the form ... and that would be rather dangerous.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I had posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well I just needed to add

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=\"UTF-8\"");
```

To my servlet `response`.